# How to write to an address if the address is present with other hex digits in the word

Tags: c, exploit, format-string

I wrote this code to see If I can modify the 'target' variable through format string attack in x64.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int target;
int main(int argc , char **argv)
{  
    printf(argv[1]);
    printf("\n\nTarget variable is at: %p" , &target);
    if(target)
        printf("Target Modified!");
    return 0;
}
```

Since each word in x64 has a size of 8 bytes, the address of target variable must be written in the form of 8 bytes.

But here, the problem is that the address of target variable is

0x555555755034   (of the form 0xAABBCCDDEEFF)

but since word size is 8 bytes, I have to write this address something like

0x0000555555755034    (of the form 0x0000AABBCCDDEEFF).

but when I ran the following command to see where the target variable is located in the stack, I saw that it is always present with some other hex digits like 5ecdAABBCCDDEEFF.

```
./code $(python -c 'print "\x34\x50\x75\x55\x55\x55"+"-%p"*131')
```

In order to shape it to correct address, I tried appending two "\00" before the target address like

```
./code $(python -c 'print "\x34\x50\x75\x55\x55\x55\x00\x00"+"-%p"*131')
```

but the terminal complained that '\x00' will be ignored since it terminates the string.

So my question is:
How can I write to an address which looks like 0xAABBCCDDEEFF but is present in word with other hex digits like 0xed4cAABBCCDDEEFF.

I will be glad if someone can help. Please do comment If I am not clear to you!

Comment: What do you mean "when I print words from the stack"? What's the output of `./code something`?

Comment: I have edited the post! Kindly have a look @Marco